# One CakePHP library for multiple apps

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have developed several small websites in CakePHP and one medium news site. However, the situation I am in right now is different and require some toughful analysis before proceeding, which brings me to the CakePHP community.

I am working for a company which currently uses straight PHP code to handle several websites (5 - 10) and all of them use one global includes folder which has things like Db connection, etc. The problem with all this, is that we want to upgrade everything to the latest version of PHP (Currently using 5.1) and in the process, I am thinking about upgrading our whole backend using CakePHP.

First of all is this a good idea? I get excited when working on CakePHP projects and have never had any issues.

Secondly, I have read from Cake experts that we should not add anything to the core side of Cake. However, if I am to create files that need to be accessed by all the sites, where could those go?

Currently, all the sites are OOP, but Cake is MVC. Should the global OOP classes(used by all sites) be converted to controllers/models or Vendor classes and placed in the Cake Core?

In general, what is the best approach?

[image: CakePHP multiple sites approach Image]

Comment: `of this magnitude` and `as big as this` are terms that don't really mean anything in the question. You can make a global plugins folder and put them all in there BUT that's probably a bad idea. From experience that just leads to paralysis whereby updating anything common becomes a problem (updating plugin x breaks at least one site, or at the very least might - so you don't upgrade). Better to treat all plugins as individual dependencies, i.e. each app has it's own copy of each plugin - possibly on a different commit.

Comment: Thanks AD7six. Probably, I detailed the question to the point I made it confusing. Basically, I was just trying to find out if CakePHP is suitable for that kind of system. (One CakePHP Library supporting Multiple Sites). Most likely I will create a folder inside Cake's library /lib named /includes for example and figure out a way to import it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can do that

The [layout of a standard cakephp install](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp) is:

```
root
    /app
        ..
        /Plugin
        /Vendor
        /webroot
    /lib
        /Cake
    /plugins
    /vendors
```

Everything inside the app directory is specific to one application. The root `lib`, `plugins` and `vendors` directors apply to all applications in the install. I.e. without modifying anything you can do this:

```
$ cd root
$ cp -r app newapp
```

resulting in:

```
root
    /app
        ..
        /Plugin
        /Vendor
        /webroot
    /newapp
        ..
        /Plugin
        /Vendor
        /webroot
    /lib
        /Cake
    /plugins
    /vendors
```

Any plugin or vendor that is in the `plugins` or `vendors` can be loaded, without doing anything out of the ordinary, in both applications e.g. with the following:

```
root
    /app
        ..
        /Plugin
        /Vendor
        /webroot
    /newapp
        ..
        /Plugin
        /Vendor
        /webroot
    /lib
        /Cake
    /plugins
        /DebugKit
    /vendors
```

Both applications have the option to load and use debug kit.

You can also simply [follow the instructions in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#using-one-cakephp-checkout-for-multiple-applications) which does the same thing but separating the location of common code from the applications themselves.

### Be aware of the limitations of sharing dependencies

The problem with managing multiple applications like that is that all applications are tied to the same version of cake, and the same version of all shared plugins/vendors. CakePHP is not an idle project, it is in constant development - as are, likely most plugins/vendors you choose to use. For plugins and vendors that's easy to solve, the application Plugin/Vendor folder is checked before the install-wide folders.

However, rather than have one core and n apps - it's a more robust idea to have n complete installs for n applications:

```
/root
    /myapp
        /app
            /Plugin
            /Vendor
            /webroot
        /lib
            /Cake
        /plugins
        /vendors
    /app2
        /app
            /Plugin
            /Vendor
            /webroot
        /lib
            /Cake
        /plugins
        /vendors
    etc.
```

That way a new application can for example use the current version of Cake, without affecting any existing applications at all.

Comment: Wow! Thanks alot for the thru explanation. I am aware of the limitations the first example imposes, but I really like that idea. I think once I get all sites converted over to Cake and having a robust Cake core, it will be easy to change them when there is any major upgrade to Cake. This way all the global PHP classes I can use from the current setup or new ones I will be creating that are used among all sites, can go in the Vendor folder. AWESOME!!!

Comment: As a matter of fact, I can't even wait to start testing this setup, that I will change all the dev projects I have at my home server to that setup. Cool!

Comment: @AD7six I want to have 2 cake projects, currently shared lib, while I want to share the session too, I have also posted question but no answer till now, Please if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892178/cakephp-multiple-apps-with-same-cake-library-and-shared-session

Comment: @alamnaryab "with same cake library" is not relevant to your question.

Comment: @AD7six I will have separate library but how to share session in that scenario, can we more to my Question for more discussion?

Comment: I'm telling you that _this_ question has nothing related to your question at all. Please do not hunt for people to answer your question(s).