# cakephp multiple apps with same cake library and shared session

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

I was having cakephp running application as public website of our company, boss asked me to create another application for them to manage in-office activities using the same user-accounts and their privileges.

On local development PC that project is located at `D:/wamp/www/blackstone`
I just copied `D:/wamp/www/blackstone/app` and pasted it at same location naming it `office`.

The app folder paths are:

```
D:/wamp/www/blackstone/app
D:/wamp/www/blackstone/office
```

I have committed 'isAutorized', 'Auth' & 'Session' component in 'office' appController to prevent checking for login. Apps are being accessed using the following URLs:

```
localhost/blackstone
localhost/blackstone/office
```

I want to access 'Session' of `blackstone` in `office`. I have yet to find a solution.

Currently I have `core.php` in `blackstone` as:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'cookie' => 'my_app',
        'timeout'  => 500,  // 8 hours + 20 min, 
        'cookie_path' => '/',
        )
    );
```

`core.php` in `office` app as:

```php
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'cookie' => 'my_app',
        'timeout'  => 500,  // 8 hours + 20 min, 
        'cookie_path' => '../',
        )
    );
```

and this led to a lot more changes.

What can I try and change?

Comment: Check this link. Might help in your case.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619877/access-cakephp-session-auth-from-outside-cakephp

Comment: that make sense, but I have access sessions in my secondary app using cakephp methods, for that I will have to make all that changes in every controller and views etc, that looks time taking.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging something like this, it is best to try to set the simplest, stupidest parameters least prone to errors just to ensure you can get it working first -- and then slowly increase the complexity toward what you want to use in production (eg, more secure) to see precisely where this might break.

First, make sure that in core.php make sure to set Security.level = "low" -- in both apps. Otherwise, an app does session referrer checks (if "medium") or even regenerates the session id (if "high") which would definitely prevent sharing.

The two points of complexity I see is 'defaults' => 'cake' and the corresponding 'cookie_path' values. [As the CakePHP manual says](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html), setting this to 'cake' places the server session cookie in a directory *relative to that app*.

You should instead comment out the cookie_path lines, then set 'defaults' => 'php'. This way you know that at the very least that PHP will place the session cookies in one fixed directory on your development machine.

If you must switch back to 'cake', then ensure that your 'cookie_path' parameters are in fact writing the server cookie file in a single shared directory. Actually look at the files being written into the expected directories when you are visiting both apps in the browser. If the two apps are writing session cookies into different directories, then you must fix your cookie_path params to match as the apps obviously aren't sharing. Also, depending on your CakePHP version, you might need to write this parameter as the following instead of how you have it in order for it to take effect: 'ini' => array('session.cookie_path' => '/app/dir')

Finally, double-check that the site domain, "cookie path", and every other session cookie parameter are absolutely identical. (You can check for the client-side Cake session cookies in your Chrome web inspector.) If anything mismatches, then the apps will fail to share.

Comment: absolutly, I am doing the same, my site is currently up but some other thing are broken due to this, I am debugging things, increasing session timeout to 8 hours using default php path is not working currently.